# Integration of Orbeon software interface with Marklogic

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic, orbeon, marklogic-8

I am looking for the Orbeon forms investigated for its suitability for building user interfaces on the top of xml content stored on MarkLogic with reference to

1) editing JATs XML content.

2)  keywords

3)  accessioning content  - edit catalog xml.

4)  writing reports.

Does any one could help us to just provide some basic idea about the advantage and disadvantage of using it with marklogic.

Is there any alternates are available?

Which edition would be better - professional edition or community edition?

Possible ways of doing communication with marklogic?

Thanks in advance.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Does any one have idea about how we can store form data (orbeon form i.e https://www.orbeon.com/) in Marklogic database.

Comment: Hi Arvind, to store in MarkLogic data captured in forms created with Orbeon Forms, you'll want to implement the [Orbeon Forms persistence API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/). It's a fairly simple REST API to implement; don't let yourself get scared by the documentation ;). You can do this in whatever language/technology you want, but you might also want to contact MarkLogic and check with them if they don't already have an implementation that they can share with you. You'll let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Arvind, did you find what you were looking for as far as integration with MarkLogic is concerned?